# base64 encode messes up cipher encryption

Tags: ruby, json, openssl

I need to send a cipher encrypted string in JSON through a socket.

`JSON.generate` doesn't like this and throws the error:

```
`encode': "\xF7" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
```

To work around this I just encoded it with `Base64.encode` and on the other side decoded it with `Base64.decode`

But when I go to decrypt it with the cipher I get the error:

```
`final': wrong final block length (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)
```

A quick little test I wrote to prove it was the Base64 messing things up:

```
decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("des-ede3")
decipher.decrypt
decipher.key = symkey

test = Base64.encode64(encrypted_json)
test2 = Base64.decode64(test)

puts test2 == encrypted_json #Prints true

decrypted_json = decipher.update(test) + decipher.final

puts
puts "JSON: #{decrypted_json}"
```

This code throws the same error at `decrypted_json = decipher.update(test) + decipher.final`

The `encrypted_json` was encrypted by a cipher using the same key.

Anyone have any ideas on what is going wrong? Or how to generate the JSON without having to encode it to Base64?

**Edit: Here is my JSON generator**

```
ready_to_send = JSON.generate({
   enc_json: Base64.encode64(encrypted_json),
   symkey: Base64.encode64(encrypted_sym_key)
})
```

Comment: Your test shows you trying to decrypt the base64 encoded encrypted data. That obviously won’t work, you need to base64 decode first (to get the encrypted binary data) then decrypt that. Have you just get the order wrong on the receiving end? (It should be something like encrypt → base64 encode → transfer as JSON → base64 decode → decrypt.)

Comment: @matt Oh man you are absolutely right. poor management of variables on both ends led to this! Thanks for pointing it out, would've taken all day to find.